# PhoneGap and ChildBrowser on Android, Twitter doesn't load .. only splash screen

Tags: android, twitter, cordova, childbrowser

I'm trying to load the twitter page https://mobile.twitter.com/ inside ChildBrowser on Android and it only loads a splash screen.

just to mention, I tried many websites in the same app with http:// and https:// and all of them are working including Facebook. The only problem I have is with twitter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had any luck displaying Twitter via ChildBrowser?
I'm having a similar problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865454/phonegap-cordova-childbrowser-wont-open-https-address I think I may need to revise my question, since I can open other HTTPS addresses.
It appears it's just Twitter that is posing the problem...

Comment: Since Android has a back button, I just opened the twitter on a new window rather than using child browser